# How to add instances to existed unmanaged instance group?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-compute-engine

I'm encountering an issue with Terraform GCP. I've successfully created virtual machines from an instance template using the "google_compute_instance_from_template" resource with count= var.num_instances, where the number of instances is set in a .tfvars file. However, I'm having trouble adding these newly created VMs to an existing unmanaged instance group.

To add the new VMs to the instance group, I used the following code:

```
instances = matchkeys(
   google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance.*.self_link,
   google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance.*.zone,
   [var.zone_id]
)
```

Unfortunately, when I applied these changes, the new VMs were not added to the instance group. I had to apply the changes a second time to add the VMs to the instance group.

Can you suggest a solution to this issue so that I can complete all changes with a single "terraform apply" command?

Thank you for your assistance.

What I'm expecting is for Terraform to automatically add the new instances that are created from the instance template to an existing unmanaged group from the first apply .